# Closed complex integral in an annulus

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I have the function 
$$f(z)=\frac{(e^z-1)(1-\cos(2z))}{z^4\sin(z)},$$ 
and I want to find

> $$\oint_{|z|=1}f(z)dz.$$

**What I know:**  
Let $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}|r<|z|<R\}$ be the annulus with $0\leq r<R\leq\infty$. I want/have to use the theorem that says if $p,P$ such that $r<p<P<R$, then for $f$ analytic we get 
$$\oint_{|z|=p}f(z)dz=\oint_{|z|=P}f(z)dz.$$ 
So of course I want to find limits for my annulus where $f$ is analytic, and a $P$ to replace the $|z|=p=1$ in my integral.  
Because $z=0$ and $z=n\pi$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}$) are singularities, I thought I could take as limits of my annulus $0$ and $\pi$.

**Question:**  
What can I take as my $P$? And how would I compute this integral?

Comment: It makes no difference $\;P, 1,\,\frac12\;$ or whatever with $\;0<P\le1\;$ , since the only pole of the function is at $\;z=0\;$ within the unit circle.

Answer (score 0):

First, by definition of derivative, l'Hospital or whatever:

$$\lim_{z\to0}\frac{e^z-1}z=e'(0)=1\;,\;\;\lim_{z\to0}\frac{1-\cos2z}{z^2}=\lim_{z\to0}\frac{\sin2z}{z}=2$$

and thus $\;z=0\;$ is a pole of order at most $\;2\;$ of $\;f(z)\;$. To find out the residue there let us take a few summands in the power series of the different functions there:

$$\frac{(e^z-1)(1-\cos2z)}{z^4\sin z}=\frac{\left(z+\frac{z^2}2+\ldots\right)\left(\frac{4z^2}2-\ldots\right)}{z^4\left(z-\frac{z^3}6+\ldots\right)}=\frac{\left(1+\frac z2+\ldots\right)\left(2-\frac{z^2}{24}+\ldots\right)}{z^2\left(1-\frac{z^2}6+\ldots\right)}=$$

$$\frac1{z^2}\left(1+\frac z2+\ldots\right)\left(2-\frac{z^2}{24}+\ldots\right)\left(1+\frac{z^2}{24}+\ldots\right)=\frac2{z^2}+\frac1z+\ldots$$

and thus the residue is $\;1\;$ .

Comment: What can I do with the residue?

Comment: @BertBrothers Haven't you studied the residue theorem??https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem

Comment: I'm not supposed to use the residue theorem for this question. Isn't there a way without?

Comment: @BertBrothers Perhaps there is but I can see an easy way out. If not with residues, how are you people suposed to do such a messy integral??

Comment: I got the hint to write down the Laurent decomposition and integrate the principal part and the other part separately. So I guess I would have to find $\oint_{|z|=1} 2/z^2+1/z$ and replace the $|z|=1$ with something easier to compute, but I'm not sure what

Comment: Fine, so if you take what is in my answer, then you get that $$\oint_\gamma\frac2{z^2}dz=0\;$$ and $\;\oint_\gamma kz^k\,dz=0\;,\;\;\text{for}\;\;k\ge0\;$ , so you're left *only* with the integral of the term $\;a_{-1}\;$ , which of course corresponds to the residue!